# Не получается сравнить данные в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

Есть код, при выполнении часть кода не выдает ничего, этот участок подписан комментарием. При этом до этого участка все как надо и после, причем предыдущий обращается к тем же переменным. Подскажите где косяк?

```
f=open("config2.txt",'r')
f2=f.readlines()
a1=f2[0]
a5=f2[1]
a6=f2[2]
b1=f2[3]
b5=f2[4]
b6=f2[5]
c1=f2[6]
c5=f2[7]
c6=f2[8]
type_s4et_U=f2[9]
type_s4et_R=f2[10]
print(a1[0], a5[0], a6[0], type_s4et_R[0], type_s4et_U[0])
time.sleep(1)
#этот участок ничего не выдает
if type_s4et_R[0]==1:
    #type_s4et="r"
    print("в конфиге a")
elif type_s4et_U[0]==1:
    #type_s4et="u"
    print("в конфиге b")
time.sleep(10)
#Определение типа счета
e=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/app-trading/app-header/header/app-account/div/div[1]/button/div[1]/small")
o=e.get_attribute('innerHTML')
if o=="Учебный счет":
    s4="u"
    print("счет учебный")
else:
    s4="r"
    print("счет реальный")
```

выдает

```
1 1 1 1 0
счет учебный
```

Comment: Вы сравниваете строку с числом. Строка никогда в своей жизни не будет равна никакому числу, потому что строка в принципе не является числом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя здесь: `type_s4et_R[0]==1` и здесь: `type_s4et_U[0]==1`
Сравниваются строковые данные и число. Результат всегда будет False. Подозреваю в этом дело. Хотя было бы непплохо содержимое текстового файла увидеть.

Answer (score 0):

Вы из файла получили строку, а сравниваете с integer

Comment: Не стоит публиковать чужой комментарий в качестве своего ответа.